# Temporal clause

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I can't decide whether these two sentences are both grammatically correct :

> He will go shopping after he finishes his homework.
>
> He will go shopping after he has finished his homework.

I believe that the first sentence implies that he will go shopping as soon as he finishes his homework and the second one means that he will go shopping at a certain time after he has finished his homework.

What puzzles me is that my teacher says that only the first one is correct because he says that the actions can't be simultaneous.

Comment: I disagree with your teacher, but I'm not sure I can articulate why. Both sentences seem perfectly OK to me, and have essentially identical meaning.

Comment: I also believe that they mean essentially the same thing because I have seldom encountered sentences like the second one.

Comment: I agree that your teacher is wrong. The second sentence is one I would expect to hear from a certain kind of documentary narration. "Observe the monkey. First it will clean itself. After it has cleaned itself, it will forage for food." It's a bit stilted and formal—but makes more sense in a specific context. It definitely does *not* imply both things happening at the same time.

Comment: I'm unclear why your teacher thinks *after* is a synonym for *simultaneous*.

Comment: A student is a life-long teacher; and a teacher, a life-long student. Both the sentences asked about by the author are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your teacher is wrong, though we may be missing his point. Nonetheless, if native speakers of a language hear a sentence and can make sense of it (and it sounds "well-formed"), then it is not "wrong."

Although both sentences overlap in their statement (shopping will occur sometime after homework completion), their meaning differs slightly based on how the verbs used to construe the events.

The first sentence uses the present simple tense for the subordinate clause ("after he finishes"), the second uses the present perfect. The first implies (though it doesn't require) that he is in the process of finishing the homework at the time of the utterance. In the sentence, the "claim" is primarily about temporal order. The event of completing the homework will happen prior to the event of shopping (in the future tense).

The second sentence's use of the present perfect shifts the viewpoint or perspective of the speaker/hearer to view the action of the verb from the vantage of its being complete. Because of that, it makes no "claim" on the activity at present (he may be working on his homework, but he may not have begun it yet too). And unlike the prior sentence, rather than simply ordering events, this sentence has the further implication that the homework will have all been done (of course that's implied in "finishing" but the perfect construes the event as a whole that is complete in a way that the present does not).

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use the present tense or the present perfect in the *after* subordinate clause, there is [no essential difference.](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/when-if-future-time-adverb-clauses/)  There is, however, a slight shift in topicality:

> I’ll do the dishes after I finish my homework. *I hate* _____!
>
> I’ll do the dishes after I’ve finished my homework. *I hate* _____!

All things being equal, i.e., barring a pathological aversion to either activity, I think most native speakers would choose *doing the dishes* in the first sentence and *doing homework* in the second. In the first, you are establishing a rather mundane sequence of events; changing the tense to the present prefect focuses on the time needed to complete the second task.

In your sentence, you can also cast the first clause in the present progressive, which is often used with [future meaning:](http://englishstudypage.com/grammar/present-tenses-with-future-meaning/)

> I’m going shopping after I finish/I’ve finished my homework.

Regardless of tense chosen, there is no universe subject to time and space where Event B (shopping), which will occur after Event A (homework), can be simultaneous, so I find your teacher’s comment puzzling.